# amr files properties - recording date viewer

Tags: linux, file-format, forensics, amr

I used my old Nokia phone to record some conversations. I copied the files to my computer. Files are in amr format. The problem is I don't remember when did I record those files.

Is there a property inside the amr file of a recording date?

How can i see it? (Linux preferable)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking through the AMR file specfication at [RFC-4867 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867#section-5) (and taking a glance at [OpenCORE-AMR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/)), the AMR file format does not store a timestamp of any kind.

In fact, the format is extremely simple. `#!AMR\n` (or some variation thereof) followed by speech frames.

So the answer is no, there is no such property. However, if you've still got the phone, I'd look more into interacting with the filesystem on it, that's probably storing a timestamp of some kind.